# Minimal Cover with functional dependencies (database)

Tags: database, functional-dependencies, cover

I think I understand a bit how to compute the minimal cover of a set of functional dependencies.
But there's something I don't understand.
Let's say we have these functional dependencies:

```
H --> ABCD
ABCD --> H  
B --> H
CD --> H
```

How should I compute the minimal cover of this?
Can I ignore B --> H and CD --> H or should I ignore A?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How does your textbook tell you to compute the minimal cover?

Answer (score 0):

Minimal cover is not necessarily unique. In your example B, CD and H are minimal covers.